# Level up javascript variabe to global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, scope

I'm trying to include an external JSON file in a script:

```
var locations;

$.getJSON(themeUri + '/resources/location.json', function(result){
  locations = result;
  console.log(locations); // it shows right results.
});

console.log(locations); // undef
```

`locations` isn't in the global scope. As I read, this is because async function.

So, I tried:

```
var locations;

function jsonCallback(result){
  locations = result;
}

$.getJSON(themeUri + '/resources/location.json', jsonCallback);
```

Doesn't work neither. How can I put the JSON contents in a global variable?

Comment: getJson is asynchronized  function, it's means your interpreter not wait for json request. locations variable show data after JSON request complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your initial example is that the `console.log` happens before the `async` call.

```
// 1. declaration happens
var locations;

// 3. this happens
$.getJSON(themeUri + '/resources/location.json', function(result){
  locations = result;
  console.log(locations); // it shows the right results.
});

// 2. console.log happens
console.log(locations); // undefined
```

So it makes sense that `2.` is undefined, since the callback has not yet happened.

**Possible solution:**

```js
var locations;

function fillLocations(responseJSON) {
  locations = responseJSON;
  console.log(locations); 
  // Continue to next operation…
}

$.getJSON( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', function(result){
  fillLocations(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As Andy had mentioned in his answer already, you can not put a console outside the function. You will always get `undefined` in this scenario. Possible solutions are given in the marked duplicate question.

Comment: Ok, I'm reading. It has a lot of info. Thank you very much! I think, I'm understanding now.

Comment: Finally, this answer solves the question. Thank you for your patient.